# Data modeling in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

"Politicians can receive money from many citizens, and the same citizen might donate to multiple politicians"

Im wondering if this would be a many to many relationship, and if so are would that mean that there are three entities in the model: citizens, politicians, and something like capital as the third entity

Comment: you'd almost certainly want additional data about the date time of the donation in the link table

Comment: Politicians table, Citizens table, and a linking table for citizens <-> politicians with how much money, date, etc

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is a many-to-many relationship with the link table itself also being a full entity.  Politicians, Citizens, and Donations.

```
Politicians
    ID
    Name
    ...

Citizens
    ID
    Name
    ...

Donations
    ID
    CitizenID
    PoliticianID
    Amount
    Timestamp
```

Any record of business transactions follows the same pattern: ThingsForSale, Customers, Purchases.

All of these are things you're going to want to search on, so all of them get their own unique IDs, even the link table.  Someone can buy the same thing multiple times, so there's no unique constraint on CitizenID, PoliticianID.  In fact, a timestamp is very helpful to tell multiple purchases apart.

You also want to avoid anything like `CASCADE ON DELETE` as records of purchases should normally survive forever.

Comment: Since you can donate money anonymously, would you use a null denotation anywhere in the relationship?

Comment: @JackH My inclination is to avoid nulls in your data design. If you allow nulls then it's hard to maintain data integrity. You can't tell the difference between an anonymous donation and a mistake. My first thought is to have a special anonymous Citizen and that brings its own issues. To avoid them, I'd add an intermediate Donators table which normalizes entities which can donate. This solves a lot of other problems like taking donations from corporations and other entities which are not citizens. The details of setting up Donators is worth its own question.

Comment: more than helpful, thank you! I didnt even consider non citizens in my model, time to expand and get back to the drawing board

Comment: one more question.. you mentioned that each has their own unique ID's which would lead me to believe it is non identifying, but I was not aware that you could have a many to many non identifying relationship. Thanks!

Comment: @JackH I'm not sure what you mean. What I meant is to point out that Donations gets a primary key. Join tables normally don't have a primary key because they're only used in joins. But Donations also stores data, so you're going to want to also query it as a data table. `Donations.ID` would be `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` or whatever you normally use.